# Android: Layout with middle component expand

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am trying to create the following layout.

```
+---------------------+
|     Text View       |
+---------------------+
|                     |
|                     |
|    Custom View      |
|    Expands to       |
|    extra space      |
|                     |
+---------------------+
|Button1   |Button2   |
+---------------------+
```

My layout xml looks like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView android:text="This is test text." android:id="@+id/statusTxt"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/gameView"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/gameButtonView">

            <Button android:text="Done" android:id="@+id/doneBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>

            <Button android:text="Undo" android:id="@+id/undoBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Than programatically I am adding my custom view

```
LinearLayout gameView = (LinearLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.gameView);
gameView.addView(gameBoardView, 1);
```

With the current layout it ends up looking like this.

```
+---------------------+
|     Text View       |
+---------------------+
|Button1   |Button2   |
+---------------------+
|                     |
|                     |
|    Custom View      |
|    Expands to       |
|    extra space      |
|                     |
+---------------------+
```

What this current layout does is it sticks the bottom buttons above the Custom View. Any ideas on how I can get it to render how I have described?

Comment: Can't you just take out the  android:layout_gravity="bottom" you have in the middle LinearLayout?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a RelativeLayout.  Set your TextView to alignParentTop="true".  Put your buttons in a LinearLayout with alignParentBottom="true" and then set your content in the middle to above="buttons" and below="text"

Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <!-- Text at the top -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <!-- Your game play view -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttons"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text" />

    <!-- Buttons at the bottom -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <Button
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: With your given example how do I programatically set that View element to my Custom View? Other than that I think your answer will work.

Comment: So, here's the deal with that.  You could set all that above/below stuff in the LayoutParams programmatically, but that's a pain in the butt.  I would go the easy route by putting a LinearLayout in that space with an id on it, and then just replace the contents of that LinearLayout with your game view (removeAllViews followed by addView when you want to swap a new View in there).  That way you don't have to do anything fancy with your LayoutParams in code...just instantiate it with FILL_PARENT, FILL_PARENT and you're done.

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks for the fast response and detailed example. You are a great member to the Android Community.

Comment: Thanks! Good luck with the game